# Is IWavePlayer.PlaybackStopped realiable?

Tags: naudio

I updated the NAudio assembly from 1.6 to 1.7. When seraching for information about the PlaybackStoppedEvent I came across this link: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/naudio-and-playbackstopped-problem.html

In the explanations there were question open.

So my question is, if there are any cases where PlayBackStopped event is not working realiable or if I can be sure that the playback is stopped when receiving the event?

Answer (score 0):

NAudio will raise the `PlaybackStopped` event when playback stops. So yes it is reliable. If you find an instance where this doesn't happen please report a bug.